# How can I force a font style for ALL users of Word 2010 on a computer?

Tags: microsoft-word

We have a lab with many different users. Word 2010 defaults to Calibri. They want all users to have a default of Times New Roman.  Is this possible?

Comment: You should see this [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/change-default-font-settings-styles-in-word-2010/) walkthrough for instructions.

Comment: There's a difference between a *default* and an *enforced value*. Which do you want? Do you want users to be able to select a different font, or not?

Comment: @hesse. Your linked page immediately changed to some 'warning, your machine is infected... scan now?' page.

Comment: @WinOutreach4 Oh, really? Sorry about that - I have Ad-block plus so I don't get those.

Comment: @hesse no problem... I'm quick with the old alt-F4, and malwarebytes says that I'm clean. Phew!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible and fairly easy.

Find and open the normal.dotm template (users\username\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates), change the font to your desired font and size and save it.

Distribute it to the user machines.

Every new document will open with this template and the font will default to what you set it as.

Answer (score 0):

After modify the file normal.dot to use your desired font, you can also create a Windows Script to copy this file to the users folder, so you won´t need to copy manually this file.